# Expressions similar to "at the expense of"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, prepositional-phrases

I'm struggling to expand my vocabulary. Could you please provide expressions alike to "at the expense of"? Words or phrases are all well-appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking up “at the expense of”?

Comment: Yes, I did. It means "with the loss of" in my understanding.

Comment: The point is, Joshua, that the sister site, ELL, and not ELU, is intended for basic questions that, when one has reached an adequate level of proficiency, one can answer for oneself if one does a little research on the internet. You might have got [this link](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/at-the-expense-of) there right away. If you still require more synonyms, show your own results here, and _then_ people will be more inclined to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

How about [detrimental](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/detrimental?q=detrimental) or detrimentally?

> *adjective*
>     tending to cause harm:
>     *recent policies have been detrimental to the interests of many old people*
>     *moving her could have a detrimental effect on her health*

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the phrase, “Robbing Peter to pay Paul,” which (fairly obviously) refers to doing something to benefit Paul at Peter’s expense.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit Knowledge Worlds English Grammar section. Hera you will get [Synonyms or Similar words. Antonyms/opposite words](http://knowledgeworldbd.com/synonyms-similar-words/), English Grammar, Idioms and phrases and many more.
You can also visit [knowledge world bd](http://knowledge-world-bd.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thank you for your information. It significantly helps.